# Render current page with new data

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my simple ajax code.

The request is made, I get the response but my view does not get rendered with new data. I get a new page with new html that I asked to render instead being rendered inside current page.

controller -

```
    def list
    @users = User.find(:all)
    end

    def show
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html {   render :partial => "ajaxshow" }
    format.js
    end
    end
```

view -

```
<% @users.each do |c| %>
<%= link_to c.user_id, {:action => :show, :user_id => c.user_id, :remote => true } %>
<% end %>
```

partial -

```
# cat _ajaxshow.html.erb
<div  align="left" id="user_ajax">
<table width="1000px">
<tr><th>User ID</th><th>First</th><th>Last</th><th>ID</th><th>Email</th></tr>
</table>
```

log -

```
Started GET "/users/show?remote=true&user_id=someuser" for 10.10.10.10 at 2012-04-17 04:01:09 -0400
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"remote"=>"true", "user_id"=>"someuser"}
  Rendered users/_ajaxshow.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: @pguardiario - see my comment below. I just added a js.erb but no result.

Comment: How are you adding this data? It would seems sensible to me that you have to POST this data. So the correct path would be to use the create action. You can read here http://blog.madebydna.com/all/code/2011/12/05/ajax-in-rails-3.html and here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link_to will not trigger the ajax call

```
  <%= link_to c.user_id, {:action => :show, :user_id => c.user_id, :remote => true } %>
```

First change the above code

```
 <%= link_to c.user_id, {:action => :show, :user_id => c.user_id }, { :remote => true, :method => :get } %>
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I tried these and still isnt working. I modified the link_to to make proper ajax call. And added a js.erb file with a new div tag in the div. 
All I want to do is make a ajax get request and render new data on the same page. 

`<div  align="left" id="ajax">  </div>`

`# cat show.js.erb
$('#ajax').html($('<%= render :partial => "ajaxshow" %>'))`

Comment: Check your log. You show have the following line Processing by UsersController#show as JS

Comment: Try $('#some_div_id').html(<%= render :partial => "ajaxshow" %>)

Comment: Yes, I see that on the log. But the data is not rendered. 

`Started GET "/users/show?user_id=someuser" for 10.20.30.40 at 2012-04-17 04:58:59 -0400
Processing by UsersController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"user_id"=>"someuser"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`user_id` = `'someuser' LIMIT 1
  Rendered users/_ajaxshow.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered users/show.js.erb (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 3.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)`

Comment: Just tried the javascript. Still no luck. 
My controller is users. List and show are actions. My current view(page) is /users/list, I added `<div id="ajax"></div> `tag in that view. and created show.js.erb with below line. 

`# cat show.js.erb
$('#ajax').html(<%= render :partial => "ajaxshow" %>)`

Comment: My `/layouts/application.html.erb` has 
`<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`

Comment: shall we discuss in the chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10162/ruby-rails-damn-frustrated-my-first-ajax

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a `.js.erb` file for the `User` controller action which will be called through the `format.js` call.

In `show.js.erb` use

```
$('#some_div_id').html($('<%= render :partial => "ajaxshow" %>'))
```

Anyhow the purpose of your action seems obscure to me.

Comment: I was missing this part, thanks. I added that js but still no luck.